# How Docker Container can access each other

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my **docker-compose** , i have 2 containers .
How to make this 2 containers access each other as they installed in one host without containers .
How they can see each other and their file systems

Comment: What does "see eachother" mean? Like be able to connect via a network? Or see the same filesystem?

Comment: see fileSystemts of each other

Comment: as the 2 applications in the containers installed in the same host

Comment: Why do you need two components to see the same filesystem? Can you talk more about your use case?

Comment: What you can do is create a volume and then mount that volume on both the containers while starting these containers so both of them can access the common filesystem. Read more about docker volumes at https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow inter-container communication create a common bridge network, and put both containers into the same network. The build phase assuming nothing needs to "talk" to each other does not need the --network switch.

```
docker network create jointops
docker build --network jointops -t srv1 /srv1
docker build --network jointops -t srv2 /srv2
docker run --network jointops -d -t srv1 
docker run --network jointops -d -t srv2
```

To check both machines are on the same network now issue the command

```
docker network inspect jointops
```

You should see both machines having an IP Allocation.

Ok... so how do they communicate ?
The bridge network - jointops by default will perform dns-resolution

So if srv1 has something like

```
curl -c http://srv2/bla/bla/bla
```

This will be resolved correctly.

Regarding Shared Data access ..

- Do not run 2 apps in 1 container

Instead

- create a docker volume
- run 2 separate containers

  - each container can connect to the same volume

Answer (score -1):

See [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for inter-container communication. Each container encapsulates its contents, so use ports for communication instead of trying to just openly expose the full filesystem of one container to another.

If both applications *need* access to the same filesystem, consider running both in the same container. That is supported.

Comment: Sorry I would disagree with some of this....

2 applications should not be run in 2 containers, you should run each container separately.

Shared data access - is easily accomplished using Docker Volumes. Which can be easily shared on multiple containers.

Comment: It’s clear in the Docker documentation and community discussions that there are numerous configurations possible, depending on your use-case. You, and many others here on SO and elsewhere, say not to run 2 applications in one container, and although there can be reasons to keep them separated, there are other situations where running in one container is just fine. I do agree that a shared volume is a clear solution for file sharing, *if* thats what you need.

Comment: Agreed - there can be special cases. I run Zookeeper and HBase in the same container ... But I think as a general rule the 1 Container to Rule them all rule should generally apply.